How to set the y-axis to cross the x-axis at x=0 in ggplot2?
I'm trying to create a scatter plot with ggplot, and I would like the y axis to cross the x axis at x = 0, instead of being at the left of the plot.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve :

(Graph taken from INSEE)
Here's a reproducible example
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

set.seed(123)
data_filtered <- mtcars

data_filtered$evolution        <- data_filtered$mpg - mean(data_filtered$mpg)
data_filtered$tauxpourmille    <- data_filtered$hp / 100
data_filtered$facts            <- data_filtered$wt * 1000
data_filtered$Code.region      <- sample(1:3, nrow(data_filtered), replace = TRUE)
data_filtered$Code.departement <- rownames(mtcars)

data_filtered <- data_filtered %>%
    group_by(Code.region) %>%
    slice_head(n = 2) %>%
    ungroup()

region_colors <- c("1" = "red3", "2" = "blue4", "3" = "green3")

ggplot(data_filtered, aes(x = evolution, y = tauxpourmille, size = facts, color = factor(Code.region))) +
    geom_point(shape = 1, stroke = 1.3, alpha = 0.6) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label = Code.departement),
                    box.padding = 3,
                    size = 5,
                    min.segment.length = 0,
                    force = 20,
                    segment.size = 0.5) +
    labs(x = "Evolution",
         y = "Horsepower/100") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_color_manual(values = region_colors) +
    scale_size_area(max_size = 10) +
    guides(size = "none") +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(),
          axis.title.y = element_text(),
          legend.position = "none") +
    expand_limits(x = range(data_filtered$evolution) + c(-0.3, 0.3) * diff(range(data_filtered$evolution)),
                  y = range(data_filtered$tauxpourmille) + c(-0.3, 0.3) * diff(range(data_filtered$tauxpourmille)))

Thank you.

You could use ggh4x::coord_axes_inside. See Create new axis at the center of the graph: ggplot or How to move x-axis to intercept y-axis at specific value for the bar plot without creating "artificial axes" by geom_hline?

You could use the coord_axes_inside function from the ggh4x package to place the y axis at 0 like this:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(data_filtered, aes(x = evolution, y = tauxpourmille, size = facts, color = factor(Code.region))) +
  geom_point(shape = 1, stroke = 1.3, alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = Code.departement),
                  box.padding = 3,
                  size = 5,
                  min.segment.length = 0,
                  force = 20,
                  segment.size = 0.5) +
  labs(x = "Evolution",
       y = "Horsepower/100") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_manual(values = region_colors) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 10) +
  guides(size = "none") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(),
        legend.position = "none") +
  expand_limits(x = range(data_filtered$evolution) + c(-0.3, 0.3) * diff(range(data_filtered$evolution)),
                y = range(data_filtered$tauxpourmille) + c(-0.3, 0.3) * diff(range(data_filtered$tauxpourmille))) +
  coord_axes_inside(labels_inside = TRUE)


Created on 2024-05-16 with reprex v2.1.0
